# python command saved in a variable

Tags: python

How can I run python command saved in a variable?

eg: `var_print = print("Hello")`
or: `var_subprocess = subprocess.call(["cd", "/bin"])`

like if it was saved in shell variable in unix, I would have executed the command saved in a variable by maybe typing $var_print

How do I do it within a python programs

Comment: Is this a python expression or a shell command?

Comment: There isn't exactly a "command" in python. There are expressions, statements, functions... If you want to save a function in a variable, well, the function name _is_ a variable and you could put it in other variables and call it later if you'd like. So, for putting a command in a variable in python, it sounds like you just want a function.

Comment: I don't understand how you expect this to work. When you write `var_print = print("Hello")`, what are you expecting to be "saved" in `var_print` as a result? Did you check your assumption? Now, supposing that first step did work the way you wanted. What exactly should *happen* when you "run" the "saved" value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the eval function:

```
command = 'print("Hello")'
eval(command)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two main ways:

Using a lambda function:

```py
my_func = lambda: subprocess.call(["cd", "/bin"])
my_func()
```

Or my personal favorite; using `functools.partial`:

```py
from functools import partial

my_func = partial(subprocess.run, ["cd", "/bin"])
my_func()
```